# find multiple closest values in a vector at once without "going over" (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have the following 2 vectors:

```
a = [1 3 5 7 8 9 10 15 16];
b = [2 4 14];
```

Is there a function I can use so that, for every element in `b`, I can find the index of the closest value to that element in `a` without "going over" the value I'm searching for?  The expected output would be:

```
[1 2 7]
```

I have found previous answers that address finding the closest value, but not the closest value without exceeding the values being searched for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited: now with a one-liner:

```
[~,index] = max(repmat(a,numel(b),1) + 0./bsxfun(@le,a,b'), [], 2)
'#% The 0./(0 or 1) creates a NaN mask where the condition
#% isn't met, leaving only the desired values in the matrix     
#% max ignores NaNs, conveniently
```

---

This isn't a built-in function but it is pretty simple ([link on ideone](http://ideone.com/s5IZ2e)):

```
a = [1 3 5 7 8 9 10 15 16];
b = [2 4 14];

c = bsxfun(@minus,b',a) #%' transpose b

c(c<0)=nan; #% discard the values in a greater than b
[~,ci] = min(c,[],2) #% min ignores nan
d = a(ci) #% if you want the actual values of a
```

output:

```
c =

    1   -1   -3   -5   -6   -7   -8  -13  -14
    3    1   -1   -3   -4   -5   -6  -11  -12
   13   11    9    7    6    5    4   -1   -2

ci =

   1
   2
   7

d =

    1    3   10
```